# TypeError: Class constructor Client cannot be invoked without 'new' with AWS S3Client

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yarnpkg

Recently, I've created a React app using `create-react-app`, and I'm getting the error on the following line:

```
const client = new S3Client({ // Here
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'testingout',
        secretAccessKey: 'testing out',
    },
    endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:53921',
});

client
    .send(new ListBucketsCommand({}))
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error)
```

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "s3-viewer",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.185.0",
    "@aws-sdk/credential-providers": "^3.186.0",
    "@aws-sdk/types": "^3.186.0",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.3.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.64",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "framer-motion": "^7.5.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have the latest S3 client and the required packages for making it to work. My app currently has nothing in it but the client, as I'm trying to just make it connect first.

As you can see, the target is `es6` so I don't really know what it could possibly be. I'm running it by invoking `yarn start`.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this as well, and it turned out that I had a different version of the S3 client package compared with the types, and credentials provider:

```
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.185.0", 
"@aws-sdk/credential-providers": "^3.186.0", 
"@aws-sdk/types": "^3.186.0",
```

When I upgraded the `@aws-sdk/client-s3` package to 3.168.0, then the problem went away.

Comment: I added my `package.json` on the question, I already have the latest version for most stuff.